# Method returns tuples in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, tuples

I don't see any examples of how to use tuples in Kotlin.
The errors i get on the first line (method definition) is "unresolved reference: a" and "expecting member declaration" for Int...

```
private fun playingAround : Pair<out a: Int, out b: Int> {
        if(b != 0) {
            b = a
            a = a * 2
        } else {
            b = a
            a = a * 3
        }

        return Pair(a, b)
    }
```

About the logic: b is 0 in the beginning and a has a random value.
From the second call on, we go into the else logic.

i don't feel the official doc is enough: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-pair/index.html. I did try also without the ":" after the method name like the official doc seems to imply
-same problem

Comment: You should declare the pair like `data class Pair<out A, out B>(val a: A, val b: B)`

Comment: @LaksithaRanasingha It already exists in the stdlib.

Comment: @Michael yes, I have just seen it. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to use it as parameter? how to use it as return value? how to use it as extenion function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look at the [functions chapter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html) of the kotlin reference and/or play around with the [Kotlin koans](https://play.kotlinlang.org/koans) to get familiar with Kotlin (or if, by any means, reading grammar is your favorite, have a look at the [function declaration grammar](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#functionDeclaration) instead; if you do not get what's written there, no problem. Start with the tutorials/reference instead).

One of the solutions could look like this:

```
private fun playingAround(a: Int, b: Int) = b.let {
    if (it != 0) a * 2
    else a * 3
} to a
```

or if you meant, that you actually want to pass a pair, then maybe the following is better:

```
private fun playingAround(givenPair: Pair<Int, Int>) = givenPair.let { (a, b) ->
    b.let {
        if (it != 0) a * 2
        else a * 3
    } to a
}
```

It's hard to really know what you wanted to accomplish as you didn't really specify what that is.

Extension function instead? For completeness:

```
private fun Pair<Int, Int>.playingAround() = let { (a, b) ->
    b.let {
        if (it != 0) a * 2
        else a * 3
    } to a
}
```

and of course: you do not need to use `let`, nor to use `to`, nor to use destructuring declarations, etc. There are just some of many possible solutions.

Answer (score 4):

You are using incorrect syntax. It should be something like this:

```
private fun playingAround(a: Int, b: Int): Pair<Int, Int> {
    val x: Int
    val y: Int

    if (b != 0) {
        y = a
        x = a * 2
    } else {
        y = a
        x = a * 3
    }

    return Pair(x, y)
}
```

Note that `a` and `b` are method parameter values which cannot be reassigned, so you need variables `x` and `y` to store the result.

You can write this with much shorter syntax though:

```
private fun playingAround(a: Int, b: Int) = if (b != 0) Pair(a * 2, a) else Pair(a * 3, a)
```

Comment: Thanks Jesper small problem now is I get a "val cannot be reassigned" on each of the two lines inside the if, any thoughts?

Comment: I realise i can use another variable which I just did, but doesn't seem ideal to me to use an additional variable

Comment: @JaneE My example above compiles; I don't know what you're doing that does not compile, so it's hard to say anything about it. You cannot assign a value to a `val` that has already been assigned. You could use `var` instead of `val`.

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite your code as the following:

```
private fun playingAround(a: Int, b: Int) : Pair<Int, Int> {
    val tempA: Int
    val tempB: Int
    if(b != 0) {
        tempB = a
        tempA = a * 2
    } else {
        tempB = a
        tempA = a * 3
    }

    return Pair(tempA, tempB)
}
```

And using [Destructuring Declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html#destructuring-declarations) you can write the following:

```
val (a, b) = playingAround(1, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey small problem now is I get a "val cannot be reassigned" on lines: tempB = a       and         tempA = a * 2, any thoughts?

Comment: It compiles on my side. But you try to use `var` instead of `val`

Answer (score 2):

Your function syntax is not correct. I suggest to study the documentation first.

To make this a bit more Kotlin-idiomatic, use `if` as an expression:

```
private fun playingAround(a: Int, b: Int): Pair<Int, Int> =
    if (b != 0) {
        Pair(a * 2, a)
    } else {
        Pair(a * 3, a)
    }
```